# How to stop UIWebView from loading URL immediately?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I Want to stop WebPage Loading of UIWebView while passing it another URL for Loading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType
```

method of `UIWebViewDelegate` Protocol and return `NO` for all url you don't want to load.

Example:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ([[inRequest URL] isEqual:someMyUrl]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```